# Can't think of a good name for this customized event class

Tags: c++, events, concurrency, naming

First, I wrote a class which wraps a Windows API Event (using `Wait` to wrap WaitForSingleObject, `Set()` to wrap `SetEvent()`, etc). I called it `CEvent` and was satisfied.

Now I created a class which extends CEvent, adding the functionality to count how many times the event was set, and expose that value with a `getCount()` property. With this, clients can perform as many `Wait()`'s as `Set()`'s.

Two questions, actually:

1. This sounds like some special synchronization construct I recall studying in my Concurrent Programming class, but that was ages ago and I'm not sure. Anybody knows if this is so, and if it is, how is this construct called?
2. I named my class `CCountedEvent`. Is this a good name?

Comment: `CEvent` is a pretty bad name to begin with... Why not just call it `Event` and throw it in a namespace? What is that `C` mean, "Concurrent"? Why not call it `ConcurrentEvent`?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If you are going to downvote, at least leave a comment explaining why so people can learn.

Comment: It's a naming convention we use, "C" stands for "class", "S" for struct, "I" for Interface and so on

Comment: @dario Ah. Personal preference, but I can't stand that sort of naming scheme...

Comment: @Mike That isn't how the site works. I didn't downvote the question, but I wish I could downvote your comment. Whoever did downvote must have found the question "Unclear or not useful". This is all the explanation anybody owes for a downvote. They are anonymous for a reason, and there is most definitely **no** implicit or explicit requirement that downvotes be accompanied by a comment.

Comment: the synchronization mechanism you are looking for is *semaphore*, and as long as the name makes sense to your users, it's splitting hairs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old saying is "a class does not do something, it is something". In that context, CEvent might be a good name, but only if an object of the class is an event (which I doubt).

I would suggest using EventHandler and CountingEventHandler.